# IF Else in Select Case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I use If else in Select case when?

```
Update Tab
set Quantity2 = a.Quantity
from
(
    select 
    case when D.Quantity1 > Tab.Quantity2
    then D.Quantity1 ------------> (if and else here)
    else Tab.Quantity3
    end 
    as Quantity
    from Dab D 
    inner join Tab
    on 
    D.ID = Tab.ID
)a
```

I want to have an IF ELSE block in the SELECT CASE WHEN part. Is it possible? or is there any other way?

Comment: Tag your RDBMS (like oracle, ms sql server, msaccess, etc).

Comment: done. its sql server

Comment: Yes nesting is also fine, simply what I need to do is, WHEN (cond1) THEN (VALUE1)... But, WHEN (cond2) THEN (perform another comparison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest case when statements.

Just put inner comparison in a new `case when` statement inside the `then` part of the outer statement.

```
select 
Table2.id,
case when Table2.switch=1
then
(
  case when Table1.val1>Table1.val3
  then Table1.val1
  else Table1.val3
  end
)
else
(
 case when Table1.val2>Table1.val3
 then Table1.val2
  else Table1.val3
 end
)
end out
from Table2
inner join Table1 on Table2.id=Table1.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0086/2

Comment: Please reword and put the SQL in here.  `Just but then new case when statement after the then or else.` makes little sense

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss reworded, and the sql copy pasted.

Answer (score 3):

Your base query should look more like this:

```
Update Tab
    set Quantity2 = D.Quantity1 
    from Dab D join 
         Tab
         on D.ID = Tab.ID
    where D.Quantity > Tab.Quantity2;
```

You can add a `case` in the `set` clause if you want a conditional expression.

EDIT:

If you want to check multiple conditions, just add them to the `case`:

```
Update Tab
    set Quantity2 = (case when D.Quantity > Tab.Quantity2 then D.Quantity1 
                          when . . . then . . .
                          when . . .
                          else tab.Quantity2
                     end)
    from Dab D join 
         Tab
         on D.ID = Tab.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, but what your query and my query now is doing is basically check 1 conditions. I have 3 such conditions, and also I have condition within these conditions. Sorry if its getting confusing

Comment: Yes I got that part sir, this is half of my issue. 
For example:
(Cond1): when D.Quantity > Tab.Quantity2 then D.Quantity1 

(Cond2): when D.Quantity < Tab.Quantity2 then (...here i want to perform another comparison...)

Comment: In literal terms, If Quantity > Quantity2 then Replace Quantity2 by D.Quanity1,.......... But if Quantity < Quantity2 then ....(compare D.Quantity with Quantity100 [someother column], which is bigger Replace with Quantity2